Two three-way switches and one single pole switch (in a 3-gang box), powering a second (2 gang) switch box?
Disclaimer: I am not an electrician (that's obvious). I have tried my best to figure out what I'm doing. I do plan to hire someone more skilled than myself and cover all legal/inspection requirements according to local statutes.
Now that that's out of the way:
I am trying to power my upstairs lights from a single breaker. Someone may look at this image I've managed to come up with and immediately know that it is not possible. However, I hope that is not the case and that we can at least somewhat use this general design, as most of the wires are already in place.
There is power coming from the circuit box into the upstairs 3-gang/three switch box. Two of those are three-way switches and one is a single pole. The TW switches control (1) a ceiling fan and (2) a living room light. The single pole switch goes to a string of wall sconces around the stairway.
I previously had this working, but when attempting to make the second three-way switch go to its designated location, nothing seemed to work anymore. So now I'm going crazy trying to figure out what went wrong. Perhaps I've broken some obvious electrician rule. Perhaps this isn't even possible with this design. Whatever it is, I would be SO very appreciative if a kind soul out there might lead me in the right direction.
The three-way switches are all run with /3 wire and the main power source is 12/2 on a 15amp breaker.
Here is my rough draft of a diagram:
Wiring Plan

Let me know if there is anything I can do to help clarify and a big thanks in advance.

There is no magic here.  In your plan all the neutrals and all the grounds get tied together in each box.
It is then up to to you to trace each hot to each switch and each traveler. It is time consuming but the only way. Tape to label wires will help keep you from checking things twice.

Your diagram is missing some lines.  The lines that you have might represent conduit rather than wires, but wires are what you need.  I.e. it is possible to wire correctly with conduit where your lines are.  It is also possible to wire incorrectly.
You have a line between LS1a TW CF and LS3b TW CF.  That should be two lines, switched hot (exactly one line will be hot at a time from that pair).  Plus a third line, switched hot (sometimes hot, sometimes not) that goes (possibly through the three gang box) to the light.
You have a line between LS3a TW LR and LS3b TW LR.  That should be two lines, switched hot (only one line will be hot at a time in that pair).
You do not have a line bringing power into LS5 Out.  That line should be always hot.  It could go either to the breaker box or to the three gang box.  If it goes to the three gang box, that means that you need three (two switched hot and one always hot) wires from that box to the two gang box.
In general, you are not showing neutral or grounds.  You'll need those.  If you are using metallic conduit and boxes, they can provide a ground path.
It is possible but not required for all these lights to be on the same circuit (implied by the single line from the breaker box).  If so, their neutrals can be tied together.  If not, they can't.  Neutrals should be segregated by circuit.
Grounds should be tied together.  They do not have circuits.
In the three gang box, if all lights are on the same circuit, you would tie the hot from the breaker box to jumpers to the three switches and to the always hot going to LS5 Out.  If that's too much for one nut, you might add another jumper and nut (or two).
Note:  your question suggests that these are cables rather than conduit.  I don't see how you could connect the two boxes with one cable.  You need three hots, a neutral, and a ground.  That's at least two cables, since cables usually don't have more than two hots.
